# Is "back then" or some other saying better than "About this time" to express when did an event happen?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

From this book "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> About this time, Dr. Le Lu joined my group. An expert in computer
>   vision, Le brought the passion and knowledge required to apply deep
>   learning to the challenging problems we were investigating.

following lines is the 2 paragraphs before above

> Another difficulty has been the time-consuming task of handcrafting of
>   algorithms for CAD systems. Until recently, it was necessary to
>   develop mathematical algorithms specifically tailored to a particular
>   problem. For example, when I started to develop a CAD system for
>   virtual bronchoscopy in 1997, there were no prior examples on which to
>   build [8]. My lab had to develop shape-based features to distinguish
>   airway polyps from normal airways [9, 10]. When we extended the
>   software to find polyps in the colon on CT colonography, it took about
>   five years to perfect the software and annotate the images to the
>   point where the software could undergo a robust evaluation on over
>   1000 cases [11]. It took another five years for translation from the
>   bench to the bedside [12]. Other groups found it similarly
>   time-consuming to develop, validate, and refine CAD systems for
>   colonic polyp detection.
>
> Most of our CADs used machine learning
>   classifiers such as committees of sup- port vector machines, which
>   appeared to be superior to other approaches including conventional
>   neural networks, decision trees and linear discriminants [13–18].
>   About two years ago, I heard about “deep learning”, a new
>   up-and-coming technology for machine learning [19]. Deep learning was
>   the name given to an improved type of neural network having more
>   layers to permit higher levels of abstraction. Deep learn- ing was
>   finding success at solving hard problems such as recognizing objects
>   in real world images [20, 21]. An aspect of deep learning that caught
>   my attention was its ability to learn the features from the training
>   data. I had long been unhappy with CAD systems that required
>   hand-chosen parameters and hand-crafted features designed for a
>   particular application. I realized early on that such hand-tuning
>   would not be reliable when the CAD software was applied to new data.
>   In addition, the hand- tuning was very time-consuming and fragile. One
>   could easily choose parameters that worked well on one dataset but
>   would fail dramatically on a new dataset. Deep learning had the appeal
>   of avoiding such hand-tuning.

Is "back then" or some other saying better than "About this time" to express when Dr. Le Lu joined the group?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on context. If the author is talking about something that happened in a particular time frame then the quoted sentence is fine. For example

> *In September 2016 we were having problems with X. About this time Dr Le Lu joined my group ...*

On the other hand, if there is no time frame reference you would need to provide one for it to make sense.

> *In about September 2016 Dr Le Lu joined my group...*

*back then* doesn't really work here. It is often associated with comparison to the present.

> *Back then we did X, but now we do Y*